# Why Can I Edit One Question But Not Another?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

**Background Information:**

- We're still in private beta, so all users have all privileges.
- Both questions are not community wiki.  They are standard, normal questions.

**No `edit` option on this question, which has a nasty typo I wanted to fix:**
[Where can I get cheap light housings?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/263/where-can-i-get-cheep-light-housings)

**I have the `edit` option here:**
[How to diagnose a starter motor that does not work](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/275/how-to-diagnose-a-starter-motor-that-does-not-work)

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question can be found on Meta SO:      [Someone with <2000 rep edited my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78447/someone-with-2000-rep-edited-my-answer)

It can also be found in this blog post:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/

According to the blog article, **anyone** can edit posts older than 12 hours as a suggested edit that requires approval, but the edit option is hidden for posts newer than 12 hours, unless the user has the privilege for editing questions and answers.  This is 2000 reputation on the released sites but may be lower on public beta sites and even lower on private beta sites.

Comment: I'm not sure how that answer actually applies to the situation you described, when we were still in private beta and everyone had all privileges.  Presumably the private beta privileges included full edit (not just edit suggestion) privileges.

Comment: @Iszi - In private beta, we have many privileges, but I don't think we have *all* privileges.  For instance, we couldn't lock or protect questions or access 10k moderator tools.  I'm not in any other private beta at the moment though to actually verify what privileges we did and didn't have.  I think "edit" was on the list of the very few privileges we didn't have access to, just suggested edits.