# missing retag option

Tags: discussion, retagging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Can I Edit One Question But Not Another?](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45/why-can-i-edit-one-question-but-not-another)

I have a rep of 637 and I have the ability to retag some questions but not others.

I can see retag on [Turn signal clicks randomly](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/316/5)

I cannot see retag on [Best Ways to Pass Emissions](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/340/5)

**EDIT**

In case anything changes:
[image: Missing retag & edit]

Is there some other criteria in determining whether I have retag privileges?

Comment: @Dori that's not related to my question at all.  I have the rep to retag a question even if the site is not in private beta.  The linked 'duplicate' question was related to users with < 2000 rep editing a question.

Comment: @Dori ok, I thought that 12 hour limit applied to just edits.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dori I just checked on the 'missing' options and they still have not appeared, and the post is 20 hours old now.  Any thoughts?